# How do i create a background of auto sliding image in eclipse

Tags: javascript, android, css, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and Android development. I am developing an app and will like to make the first screen that appears after my splash screen have a background made of pictures in a form of a slide show with 5secs between each picture. I have no idea how to get around this and would appreciate every useful material that could guide me to get this done. counting on your brilliant ideas. I also need to know which format the pictures should be in and if they all have to be of the same dimension. 
Thanks.

Edited with codes included.

```
package com.joel.mybusapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Animation slide_in_left, slide_out_right;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.bckgrndViewFlipper1);

    slide_in_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
          slide_out_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

          viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);
          viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);               

        //sets auto flipping
          viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
          viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
          viewFlipper.startFlipping();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.joel.mybusapp.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndViewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen6"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen6png" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen5"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen5png" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen3"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen3png" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen2png" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen1png" />
    </ViewFlipper>            

</LinearLayout>
```

I managed to get the background auto sliding with ViewFLipper and ImageView tools. the code above works fin only that there is a white boarder around by screen which i want to disappear. I have literally made every container to fill_parent but the white boarder still remains. A screen shot of what i mean is below. I need some help to get rid of the white boarder.
[image]

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far. Just use the format they're currently in right now. Don't be afraid of making mistakes. You can always optimize the end result later on.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thanks. I have updated the question with the code so far.

Comment: Where is your image?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thanks. My images are in the res/drawables-hdpi folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below fixed all issues addressed in the question thanks to ideas from @Frederick nyawaya

Activity_Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    tools:context="com.joel.mybusapp.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndViewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen6"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen6png" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen5"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen5png" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen3"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen3png" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen2png" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bkscreen1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backscreen1png" />

        </ViewFlipper>            

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.joel.mybusapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Animation slide_in_left, slide_out_right;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.bckgrndViewFlipper1);

    slide_in_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
          slide_out_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

          viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);
          viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);               

        //sets auto flipping
          viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
          viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
          viewFlipper.startFlipping();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewFlipper. You will need to add ImageViews with required bitmaps and start flipping the view. The images should be in your res/drawables dir, PNG or JPEG but ofcourse they'll be loaded as bitmaps. They don't need to be of the same size, use the SCALE TYPE property of the ImageView to adjust their appearance.

Comment: Thanks. Im not sure how the concept works so i got a little confused. Do i have to alternate adding the imageViews and viewflipper for each picture or do i add all the imageViews first and then add one singe viewFlipper to flip the views?.

Comment: Thanks @fredrick . Im not sure how the concept works so i got a little confused. Do i have to alternate adding the imageViews and viewflipper for each picture or do i add all the imageViews first and then add one singe viewFlipper to flip the views?. Also what values of viewFLipper do i have to set for the transition to occur automatically after every 5secs from right to left and to start once the page/view loads

Comment: @fredrick Where do i need to add exceptions to avoid my app crushing?